# What surveys will show the number of people who live in single family homes?

Tags: data-request, housing, data, urban-economics

I'm looking for any source of data showing the number of people who report living in a single family home for a given year. I've already tried the Current Population Survey and the American Housing Survey but haven't had much luck. Ideally, I'd like this to go back as far as possible.